# What am I doing wrong here? WordPress database error

Tags: database, errors

I'm just trying to insert values into custom table of wordpress and it throws me this error

```
WordPress database error: 
[You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'( post_id, site_id, u_id, is_present ) 
VALUES ( 989, 139, '1' at line 2]
INSERT INTO ( post_id, site_id, u_id, is_present ) VALUES ( 989, 139, '10822456', 'false' )
```

I'm using prepare query to Protect Queries Against SQL Injection Attacks.

Here is my code

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
"
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->wp_plugs
    ( post_id, site_id, u_id, is_present )
    VALUES ( %d, %d, %d, %s )
",
    $post_id,
    $site->ID,
    $u_id,
    'false'
) );
```

Comment: Two notes: Regarding your tags, is the site hosted on [tag:wordpress.com]? And could you please care a bit more about formatting the next time you ask a question (or write an answer)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kaiser,No its not hosted on WordPress.com.I'm working on my local.Actually I'm new into WordPress,also new to stack exchange.Next time i will format it better.Thank you.

Comment: I didn't have a problem running this, are you sure your table is called `wp_wp_plugs`? `$wpdb` will actually prefix your tables so `wp_posts` becomes `$wpdb->posts` since the default prefix is `wp_`. Another thing to check is that the fields correspond with the values in the database, types match up, names match up, etc. Another thing to check is `$u_id`, it says you're passing a value of `'1' at line 2` which sounds like there's an error what what you're passing.

Comment: unless you've explicitly created a member var in `$wpdb` that contains your table name, `$wpdb` isn't "aware" of custom tables. the core tables are hardcoded into `$wpdb`, which is why you can use `$wpdb->posts`, etc.. always use `$wpdb->prefix` plus your table name, as the prefix may not be `wp_`.